# Parse data per date from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to make an attendance system to keep track of users from my gaming community. As of right now, I would like to show true or false based on dates given in the database to what is current this month (dates 1-11). As the days progress during the month, the application would do the same.

Thanks in advance, been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Here is what I am currently getting
[image]

My current code

```
include('../../config/protection.php');
include('../../config/db.php');
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
//Date formating
$dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";

$begin = new DateTime( 'first day of this month' );
$end = new DateTime( 'last day of this month' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
$daterange2 = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);


$date = new DateTime();
$date1 = new DateTime();
$dateString = $date1->format($dateFormat);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($dateString);
$month2 = date('j', $timestamp2);
//generating days of the month
$month = date('m', $timestamp2);
$year = date('Y', $timestamp2);

//select username ane id
$sql = "SELECT * from rosters,ranks
inner join user_ranks on user_ranks.rank_id=ranks.id
where rosters.ruser_id = user_ranks.user_id
GROUP BY rosters.rname 
ORDER BY ranks.id";

$results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(!$results and $mysqliDebug) {
    echo "<p>There was an error in query: $results</p>";
    echo $con->error;
}
?>
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center">Rank/Name</th>
            <th class="center">Promotion Date</th>
            <?php
            foreach($daterange as $date)
            {
            echo '<th class="center">'.$date->format("d") . "</th>";
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

<?php
// $rows = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) )
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['rname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>N/A</td>";

    $userid1 = $row['ruser_id'];
    // $rows[] = $row;
    $attendsql = "SELECT * from attendances where user_id=$userid1";
    $attendresults = mysqli_query($con, $attendsql);
    $arows = array();

    while( $arow = mysqli_fetch_array($attendresults) )
    {
        $arows[] = $arow;
    }

    foreach($daterange as $date1)
    {
        foreach ($arows as $arow ) 
        {
            $date1String = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
            $createdOnDate = $arow['created_on'];
            $createdDate = new DateTime( $createdOnDate );
            $attendanceDateString = $createdDate->format('Y-m-d');

            if ( $attendanceDateString == $date1String )
            {
                echo '<td>True</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td>False</td>';
            }
        }
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}





?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And what's the problem you are getting?

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee Essentially its not returning true on the dates that do exist in the database. It will equal true on the first one then false for the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your loop to this:

```
foreach( $daterange as $date1 )
{
    $attended = FALSE;

    foreach ( $arows as $arow ) 
    {
        $date1String          = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
        $createdOnDate        = $arow['created_on'];
        $createdDate          = new DateTime( $createdOnDate );
        $attendanceDateString = $createdDate->format('Y-m-d');

        if ( $attendanceDateString == $date1String )
        {
            $attended = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if ( $attended )
    {
        echo '<td>True</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>False</td>';
    }
}
```

Basically, it looks like you're printing out a response for every row in the db for every date, rather than just one value per date.

Comment: If I could send you a beer and some cake, I would do it right now. This has been plaguing me for a few days. Looking at how easy this is, I want to kick myself in butt. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!! <3

Answer (score 2):

You should write  this. This will solve your problem.

```
    include('../../config/protection.php');
    include('../../config/db.php');
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
    //Date formating
    $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";

    $begin = new DateTime( 'first day of this month' );
    $end = new DateTime( 'last day of this month' );
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
    $daterange2 = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);


    $date = new DateTime();
    $date1 = new DateTime();
    $dateString = $date1->format($dateFormat);
    $timestamp2 = strtotime($dateString);
    $month2 = date('j', $timestamp2);
    //generating days of the month
    $month = date('m', $timestamp2);
    $year = date('Y', $timestamp2);

    //select username ane id
    $sql = "SELECT * from rosters,ranks
    inner join user_ranks on user_ranks.rank_id=ranks.id
    where rosters.ruser_id = user_ranks.user_id
    GROUP BY rosters.rname 
    ORDER BY ranks.id";

    $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(!$results and $mysqliDebug) {
        echo "<p>There was an error in query: $results</p>";
        echo $con->error;
    }
    ?>
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center">Rank/Name</th>
                <th class="center">Promotion Date</th>
                <?php
                foreach($daterange as $date)
                {
                echo '<th class="center">'.$date->format("d") . "</th>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    // $rows = array();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) )
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['rname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>N/A</td>";

        $userid1 = $row['ruser_id'];
        // $rows[] = $row;
        $attendsql = "SELECT * from attendances where user_id=$userid1";
        $attendresults = mysqli_query($con, $attendsql);
        $arows = array();

        while( $arow = mysqli_fetch_array($attendresults) )
        {
            $arows[] = $arow;
        }

        foreach($daterange as $date1)
{
        $attended = FALSE;
    foreach ($arows as $arow ) 
    {
        $date1String = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
        $createdOnDate = $arow['created_on'];
        $createdDate = new DateTime( $createdOnDate );
        $attendanceDateString = $createdDate->format('Y-m-d');

        if ( $attendanceDateString == $date1String )
        {
            $attended = TRUE;
                    }
    }
    if ($attended)
    {
                    echo '<td>True</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                    echo '<td>False</td>';
            }

}

        echo "</tr>";
    }


    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This will solve your problem